# how to change Second Drop-downs Datasourse based on 1st Drop-down change in KendoGrid inline Edit reactive forms Angular 6

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid Inline Edit Reactive forms with multiple Kendo Drop-downs in it. How I can change the Datasource of the second Drop-down on change of 1st Dropdown.basically all the rows second dropdowns data source can be different.

Answer (score 0):

Use cascade `dropdownlist` inside kendo grid editor, this is jQuery example but I think it's not hard to implement it in Angular:

```
columns: [
        { field: "id" },
        {
            title: "Brand",
            field: "brandId",
            template: "#= brandName(brandId) #",
            editor: function(container) { 
                var input = $('<input id="brandId" name="brandId">');
                input.appendTo(container);

                input.kendoDropDownList({
                    dataTextField: "name",
                    dataValueField: "brandId",
                    dataSource: brands
                }).appendTo(container);
            }
        },
        {
            title: "Model",
            field: "modelId",  
            template: "#= modelName(modelId) #", 
            editor: function(container) { 
                var input = $('<input id="modelId" name="modelId">');
                input.appendTo(container);
                input.kendoDropDownList({
                    dataTextField: "name",
                    dataValueField: "modelId",
                    cascadeFrom: "brandId",
                    dataSource: models+
                }).appendTo(container);
            }
        },
        { command: "edit" }
        ]
```

Documentation example: [Cascade DropDown Editor](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/cascading-dropdown-editors)

Comment: jQuery is not an option for me. I need to figure out within Angular

Comment: found one way of achieving this. use the directive [data]="callaFunction(dataItem.firstDropDownModelId)" in kendo dropdown and based on 1st DropdownId i can filter the list and return the result